# Configure uWSGI (+cherokee) to run as a specified user?

Tags: cherokee, uwsgi

I have a cherokee serving django app using uWSGI. 
I want the uwsgi process user and group to be specified by me - how do I do this?
(now uwsgi runs as 'www-data' user)

Answer (score 1):

You could `chown <user>:<group> /path/to/uwsgi` and then specify this user/group in the cherokee admin panel (sources).
Make sure to restart cherokee after that change.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, would be to start the uWSGI yourself, instead of letting Cherokee handle this, another would be starting the uWSGI processes through an init script. Both options allow you to set a user easily.